# How can I restart move_base server?

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sometimes I will encounter such a problem: due to the positioning error of AMCL, during the execution of the target sent to move_base, the robot will be considered to collide with an obstacle or get stuck in the wall. At this time, the target is Aborted, but move_base will not respond to subsequent targets. I have tried requesting `clearmap` and using AMCL's `request_nomotion_update`, but the effect is not very immediate. But I found that starting a move_base node with the same name through the launch file to force the previous move_base to close, so as to restart move_base, can effectively solve this problem, and can go to the next target point normally. So I want to know if it is possible to restart the move_base server or node in C++ (some kind of API?) to achieve the same effect, instead of forcing the old node out by using the node with the same name.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/393505/how-can-i-restart-move_base-server?/) by [Laura](https://answers.ros.org/users/86601/laura/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2021-12-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-12-30**:
Hi @Laura:

Have you considered using `resetState`. Below the code, perhaps you can create a method to do something not as drastic as well.

```
  void MoveBase::resetState(){
    state_ = PLANNING;
    recovery_index_ = 0;
    recovery_trigger_ = PLANNING_R;
    publishZeroVelocity();

    //if we shutdown our costmaps when we're deactivated... we'll do that now
    if(shutdown_costmaps_){
      ROS_DEBUG_NAMED("move_base","Stopping costmaps");
      planner_costmap_ros_->stop();
      controller_costmap_ros_->stop();
    }
  }
```

https://github.com/strawlab/navigation/blob/master/move_base/src/move_base.cpp

**Comment by [Laura](https://answers.ros.org/users/86601/laura/) on 2021-12-31**:
@osilva,Thank you very much for your solution. ROS is a very large system for beginners like me. I also need to learn more about the source code and interfaces. Thank you again for your patient answers all the time!

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-12-31**:
Hey @Laura I learned every day in this forum that’s what I like the most. Thank you for asking too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @Laura, adding this as an answer for future use.

Consider `resetState()` method. Below the code on how it works.

```
  void MoveBase::resetState(){
    state_ = PLANNING;
    recovery_index_ = 0;
    recovery_trigger_ = PLANNING_R;
    publishZeroVelocity();

    //if we shutdown our costmaps when we're deactivated... we'll do that now
    if(shutdown_costmaps_){
      ROS_DEBUG_NAMED("move_base","Stopping costmaps");
      planner_costmap_ros_->stop();
      controller_costmap_ros_->stop();
    }
  }
```

https://github.com/strawlab/navigatio...

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2022-01-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Laura](https://answers.ros.org/users/86601/laura/) on 2022-01-02**:
@osilva Thank you very much！ I recently modified the source code of move_base so that this function will be called automatically under preset error conditions.

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2022-01-02**:
Great